# I am getting " java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3 "

Tags: java, string, exception

SentiWord method takes String arguments and uses tagger method to tag a word as verb or noun....etc When I run this code I get "  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3 ". I know there are similar questions like this, but I am unable to apply them to get rid of exception.

```
public static String SentiWord(String stri) {
       MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
           String sample=stri;
            sample = sample.replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", "");
            String[] words = sample.split("\\s+");
           String taggedSample = tagger.tagString(sample);
            String[] taggedWords = taggedSample.split("\\s+");
           double totalScore = 0;
            SWN3 test = new SWN3();
            for (int i=0; i<taggedWords.length;i++) {   
               String tail = taggedWords[i].substring(words[i].length() + 1);
                ....
                ...
                }
```

What I am trying:

```
if (words[i].length()>0)   // This line
             tail = taggedWords[i].substring(words[i].length() + 1);
```

But exception doesnt seem to go.Please help.

Comment: `taggedWords` and `words` are different array with different length

Comment: change your condition to - `if (taggedWords[i].length() >= words[i].length)`

Comment: When posting exceptions, please always include the stacktrace, since that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @RamanShrivastava ,  you are right. I corrected it.

Comment: And @RolandIllig I will keep that in mind next time :) Regards

Answer (score 1):

obviously the `words[i]` is longer than `taggedWords[i]`
Try to print them both for debug purposes and I bet that this is what you'll see.